# On button click, close the application Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a java application, want to close the GUI with confirmation window to close the application

for example:-

```
        frmViperManufacturingRecord.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frmViperManufacturingRecord.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                JFrame frame = (JFrame)e.getSource();

                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Are you sure you want to close the application?", "Please Confirm",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
            });
```

This is working [fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKR08.png), when I press the window close (x) button, but I want to bring this event to a button to perform the action 'On Click', since I am newbie finding difficulties to bring it inside the 'actionPerformed'

So far I have tried the code below and it didn't work...

```
        //close window button
        JButton btnCloseWindow = new JButton("Close Window");
        btnCloseWindow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //frmViperManufacturingRecord.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                //frmViperManufacturingRecord.dispose();
                //System.exit(0);
                JFrame frame = (JFrame)e.getSource();

                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Are you sure you want to close the application?", "Please Confirm",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
```

Please give me some directions on this, thanks

Comment: Thanks @user2408578, System.exit(0) works fine, but want a confirmation window before close the application, thanks

Comment: didnt get it I said try it in if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){ } ....

Comment: Thanks @user2408578, it gives an [error](http://i.imgur.com/VwOT4oY.png), thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    frame.dispose();
            }
```

Also note CastException on the line 122.

Instead of

```
JFrame frame = (JFrame)e.getSource();
```

change to:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

Comment: Thanks @user2902894, I did try both of your options System.exit(0) and frame.dispose(); both throws an [error](http://i.imgur.com/VwOT4oY.png), thanks

Comment: It seems its throwing an error on other line, can you post line on which this exception is thrown?

Comment: Thanks @user2902894, error line 122 is "JFrame frame = (JFrame)e.getSource();" and have posted the complete [code](http://jsfiddle.net/yL9coavw/) here, thanks for your time and help

Comment: The problem is in your casting. You can not cast an object of ActionEvent type to JFrame.

Comment: Change JFrame frame = (JFrame)e.getSource(); on line 122 into: JFrame frame = new JFrame();

Comment: you are diamond @user2902894, can you please edit your answer to accept it, please, worked beautifully....thanks

Comment: frame.dispose() will not always guarantee your application will exit. Most of the time it will. `System.exit(0)` is safer.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

to

```
if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
  System.exit(0);
}
```

`frame.setDefaultCloseOperation` is what happens when someone clicks the 'x' to close the window. Every other way to exit is controlled by you. The best way is to have your window closing listener and action listener call the same method that will pop up the dialog and call `System.exit(0)` if the user wants to exit. This will also help you with cleanup operations.

Sample code:

```
public class Test extends JPanel implements WindowListener {
    public Test() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JLabel("This is a test."), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton b = new JButton("Exit");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                exit();

            }
        });
        add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        Test t = new Test();
        f.add(t, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.addWindowListener(t);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        exit();

    }

    private void exit() {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @markbernard, have tried, but it throws an error, Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0". [error](http://i.imgur.com/VwOT4oY.png)

Comment: `System.exit(0)` would not cause a ClassCastException. There must be something else wrong. I have added some code to show a working example.

Comment: Thanks @markbernard, error is not in System.exit(0) but @ line 122 is error as pointed out by _user2902894_ "JFrame frame = (JFrame)e.getSource();", have changed to "JFrame frame = new JFrame();", worked now, thank you so much for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

if still not working then try

```
frame.setVisible(false);
frame.dispose();
```

in if(result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){} block

Comment: Thanks @user2408578, still gives the same error. thanks

Comment: what is exception...pls paste the stack trace

Comment: Thanks @user2408578, have paste the complete [stackTrace](http://jsfiddle.net/v52re3x7/), thanks

Comment: read this line "java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JButton cannot be cast to javax.swing.JFrame".So you can not cast a button (i.e. current event) to jframe...

Comment: just comment this line and try System.exit(0) in if block...it should work

Comment: Thanks @user2408578, error was in above the line 122, fixed it thanks for your time.